# Can I do a dynamic comparison on SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this model:

```
class PUC(Base):
   pucId = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   asset = Column(TINYINT)
   article = Column(TINYINT)
   more values ...
   more values ...
```

And I need to do a query dynamically (This way I tried):

```
pucs = session.query(PUC).filter(PUC[unique_by_param] == 1).all()
```

The value of `unique_by_param` come from the Frontend.
An example of `unique_by_param` is: `{str}'asset'`, `{str}'article'`, `{str}'another_model_value'`

What I really need is a way to do.
`session.query(PUC).filter(PUC.asset == 1)` or `session.query(PUC).filter(PUC.article == 1)` dynamically, like the first way I tried.

The result using (`PUC[unique_by_param]`) is `TypeError: 'DeclarativeMeta' object is not subscriptable`

There is a way I have used before, but isn't pretty way to do that, but isn't pretty way to do that:

```
# this is a accounting table, so this have around 250 columns 
#and this special columns be around 70 variables... 
#So this isn't an option o do this.
if unique_by_param == 'asset':
    q = (PUC.asset == 1)
elif unique_by_param == 'article':
    q = (PUC.article)
elif ...more values:

pucs = session.query(PUC).filter(or_(*q))
```

Comment: If `PUC.asset` is a `TINYINT`, and not a `bool` type, then what are you expecting `PUC.asset == True` to do?

Comment: Yes, it's a bool. So if i have this checked, the value of the `pucs` is totally different @cricket_007

Comment: No, your column is a `TINYINT`, not a `BOOLEAN` value....

Comment: already, this way it's better @cricket_007 `PUC.asset == 1'

Comment: @AdrianSerna Does the method you tried fail in some way?

Comment: @this-vidor, already edited with the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses `filter_by` and [keyword argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
keyword = {unique_by_param : 1}
session.query(PUC).filter_by(**keyword).all()
```

Comment: Yes, it's a great solution but **EXTREMELY DANGEROUS**. I need one way to do dynamically but safe at the same time.

Comment: @AdrianSerna I'm thinking I should delete it, since it's such bad advice. I believe the second (updated) answer is safer.